# PostgreSQL - if clause in select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT nickname, name from users;
```

Some users have name but don't have nickname and some have nickname but do not have name. I want to have sql query that checks if user have present name or nickname and return only present one. Here is how the result should look like:

```
Name
-------------
user_1_nickname
user_2_name
user_3_nickname
user_4_name
```

Is there way to do that in PostgreSQL?

Comment: If a user has both, which one to chose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use coalesce?

```
select coalesce(name, nickname) -- this prioritises name over nickname
from users;
```

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try with `coalesce`. It could be what you need.

`Coalesce` returns the first not null argument in the list, so you can do something like:

`coalesce(nickname, name)` and then where nickname is null, name is returned.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html